# `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model>("{float: NaN}")` fails

Tags: json.net

Newtonsoft's Json.Net is obviously capable of deserializing NaN, but I can't seem to coerce it to do it into a provided float field. I get an `Unexpected character "N"` exception.

In the following code:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace TestNanDeserialize
{
    public class Number
    {
        public float Float;
    }

    public class Empty
    {
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private const string testJson = "{float: NaN}";

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Succeeds();
            Fails();
        }

        private static void Succeeds()
        {
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Empty>(testJson);
        }

        private static void Fails()
        {
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Number>(testJson);
        }
    }
}
```

`Succeeds()` and `Fails()` generate two very different call stacks:

**`Succeeds()`**

```
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumberNaN() Line 2299   C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue() Line 1572   C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read() Line 381  C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(object newObject, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, string id) Line 2331   C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, object existingValue) Line 485    C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, object existingValue) Line 291 C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, bool checkAdditionalContent) Line 167 C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) Line 823  C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) Line 802  C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) Line 863 C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestNanDeserialize.Empty>(string value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) Line 820 C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestNanDeserialize.Empty>(string value) Line 757  C#
TestNanDeserialize.exe!TestNanDeserialize.Program.Succeeds() Line 26    C#
TestNanDeserialize.exe!TestNanDeserialize.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 20   C#
```

**`Fails()`**

```
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsDouble() Line 948  C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, bool hasConverter) Line 2214 C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(object newObject, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, string id) Line 2359   C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, object existingValue) Line 485    C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract containerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty containerMember, object existingValue) Line 291 C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, bool checkAdditionalContent) Line 167 C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) Line 823  C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType) Line 802  C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value, System.Type type, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) Line 863 C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestNanDeserialize.Number>(string value, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings) Line 820    C#
Newtonsoft.Json.dll!Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestNanDeserialize.Number>(string value) Line 757 C#
TestNanDeserialize.exe!TestNanDeserialize.Program.Fails() Line 31   C#
TestNanDeserialize.exe!TestNanDeserialize.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 21   C#
```

You might think that should be enough for debug this, and perhaps it should, but it doesn't actually make obvious to me what forks were supposed to have occurred differently in all of these layers to make it work.

EDIT: Yes, I'm aware that unquoted NaN is not valid JSON. A stated feature of Json.Net is support for NaN. It obviously is capable of deserializing it, as the code above demonstrates. I'm not certain, however, that it can deserialize into a float field.

NOTE: I've opened a defect for this at: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/908

Comment: *"Newtonsoft's Json.Net is obviously capable of deserializing NaN"*. I wouldn't assume so. `NaN` is not part of the JSON specification. Therefore, the example you've posted isn't actually valid JSON.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm aware that it isn't valid JSON. And yet it is frequently used. Your comment is unrelated to my statement that Json.Net is obviously capable of this, and I assumed nothing. My statement is based on fact, as demonstrated by the code I provided above. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of your difficulty is that your [JSON is invalid](http://json.org/) -- specifically the symbol `NaN` needs to be *quoted*.  I.e. the following JSON can be deserialized into your `Number` class:

```
{"float": "NaN"}
```

And the following cannot:

```
{float: NaN}
```

Note that there is a setting, [`FloatFormatHandling.Symbol`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_FloatFormatHandling.htm), that allows `NaN` to be output without quotes, so it may be earlier versions of Json.NET were able to parse non-quoted `NaN` strings as `float` or `double`.  But that seems not to be the case currently.  See [Serializing NaN results in non-JSON compliant text](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/1) and also [Json.NET 5.0 Release 1: Serializing NaN and Infinity Floating Point Values](http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2013/04/07/json-net-5-0-release-1-net-4-5-biginteger-read-only-collections).

**Update 2**

I tried deserializing the unquoted JSON string `{float: NaN}` in various versions of Json.NET:

- 8.0.2 (current): fails.
- 7.0.1: succeeds.
- 3.5: succeeds.

So this may be a regression.  You might want to [report an issue](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues).

**Update**

As pointed out by @shannon, there's an inconsistency in Json.NET's extensions to the JSON standard.  `JToken.Parse("NaN")` returns a `JValue` of type `Float`, but `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<double>("NaN")` throws an exception.  It's possible to use this inconsistency to write a converter that handles non-quoted `NaN` strings:

```
public class FloatNanConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(float) || objectType == typeof(float?);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var value = JValue.Load(reader);
        if (objectType == typeof(float?))
            return (float?)value;
        else
            return (float)value;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { false; } }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thank you. It is also interesting that it can be deserialized into an anonymous type without issue.

Comment: Also, FYI, quite aware that NaN is not valid JSON. Whether that is "the problem" is a matter of perspective.

Comment: @shannon - that's interesting -- if I do `JToken.Parse()` on your json the `NaN` value comes back as a `JValue` of type `Float` not `String`.  So there appears to be an inconsistency in Json.NET's extensions to the JSON standard.  by "problem" I only meant "thing that causes Json.NET to fail".

Comment: Yes, totally agree. That was why I included the stack trace to `ParseNumberNaN()` above. It was not clear, to say the least.

Comment: OTOH, if you think about it, deserializing quoted `"NaN"` as an anonymous type would have to result in a string. So this is "required" or "symmetric" (if you will) functionality.

Comment: @shannon - answer updated.  This may be a regression in Json.NET 8.0.

Comment: Thank you for the converter. I was just researching how to integrate such a thing, and will use it immediately. (especially since I'd already given you the point)

Comment: @shannon I would say that the problem is that JSON.NET will output invalid JSON and then it can't deserialize it with the same settings.

Comment: @FINDarkside: I sort of agree. I would prefer for a robust product to output valid formats, but still accept invalid-but-commonly-used formats (as NaN is). I suspect this product intends to do so, but as dbc suggested is simply showing a regression.

Comment: It would at least make sense, to me, to be able to deserialize it as a string, and then coerce a string value of 'NaN' into a float, when the model I ask it to deserialize to has a float property of the same name.